# Calendar control "Expedia.com"

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my webpage I want to design a calender control similar to the calender control present in the "Expedia.com" link.

In the link the calender calendar control is designed using

-> unable to enter anything into text box (calender dependent text box) -> I dont know the exact technical term ;)

-> even on clicking the corresponding label the calendar is populated :O

-> in text box it shows light fonted dd/mm/yy

By the way I referred -> https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150655/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030202-1.aspx

```
 <!-- -->
```

Any readymade logic ? :)

Comment: Have a look at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Super!. Thank you Paul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jquery library has a nice free calendar control called DateePicker. If you [take a look here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) on the jquery website they provide some nice demonstrations of the datepicker in a variety of 'modes'.

This control is widely used in the industry and is pretty robust, also if you want to change the style of the datepicker [go here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and download the theme you like.